# edit actionscript from swf - compiled file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, swfobject

I have one swf file, it is JW Player plugin. It have one actionscript file in which is whole plugin code, and rest of files are jwplayer api files. So i need to open that file (where whole plugin code is) and edit few lines. But there is a problem, because when i try to decompile file with sothink swf decompiler (and few others) - to convert it to .FLA, decompiles simply crashes. It is because of some file from jwplayer api library. So, next thing i tried is to edit via HEX (because there is not much to be edited), but i couldn't find what i needed. So what i need is - is there any way or not? If yes, which program can be used for this?

Comment: Btw. why do you want to decompile/reverse-engineer other person's code ?

Comment: plugin i am using is free (no licences), and i need to make it more comfortable to work with, for my own usage, not for selling or redistribution..why is that problem?

Comment: If that's the case then you could probably e-mail JW Player's creator and ask for the FLA or for direction to do what you need it to do.  An application being free doesn't necessarily mean that the author is fine with it being reverse-engineered.

Comment: Isn't jwplayer already [open source](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/)? Or are you trying to decompile a jwplayer plugin? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something similar in the past.  In my scenario, the client had the SWF but no FLA.  I needed to change a hardcoded url and sothink wasn't decompiling but I could view the AS in the sothink previewer.  Luckily for me the flash wasn't very complex so I was able to copy the AS and graphics out and start a new project.  I would imagine that JW Player is much more complex so this may not be an option for you, but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: sh4nx0r has a good point.  I'm sure decompiling would violate the license agreement.  In my case I had full permission to decompile the swf.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you may be able to get what you want by [using the plugin API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/17679/building-flash-plugins) to extend the functionality or maybe even by [customizing a skin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/14/building-skins).